# self.x vs x in a function in python

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, instance-variables

I'm looking into some class and functions stuff in Python.

```
class Area():

    def area(self):
        b=int(input("enter second number"))
        print (self.b)
        print(b)

ak=Area()
ak.b=int(input("enter first number"))
ak.area()
```

When you give values the output is as

```
enter first number5
enter second number2
5
2
```

what are `b` and `self.b` here? I know `self` works like this pointer but why `b` in function is not giving error as there is no `self` before it? Why both are having diff values as both are running in a object?

Answer (score 1):

> What are b and self.b here?

`b` is a local variable. `self.b` is an instance variable.

> Why "b" in function is not giving error as there is no self before it?

`b` is a local variable inside `area`. You should understand that, within `area`, two variables are currently within scope and alive - `b` (local variable), and `self.b` (instance method which was set before the function call).

> Why both are having diff values as both are running in a object?

Just because you can access both of them inside the instance method, doesn't mean they both belong to the instance. See above.

Comment: @chowsai I would say no. Polymorphism refers to behaviour in objects, not their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
x_global = "GLOBAL"

class example:
    
    # This function will be ran when the class is initialized.
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "SELF"

    x = "LOCAL"
```

Now, in order to print the variable :

```
# Initialize the variable.
e = example()

print(e.x) # Result : SELF

print(example.x) # Result : LOCAL

print(x_global) # Result : GLOBAL
```

Conclusion :

e.x is only available when the class is **initialized** .
But, example.x is available even if the class is **not initialized** . You can call the variable whatever you want, but **e.x** is called **instance variable** , while **example.x** is called **local variable** . **x_global** is called **global variable**.

This has been tested using Python 3.9.9 , correct me if Im wrong.